# Converting 32 bit DEM to 16 bit in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I have a 32 bit DEM with resolution 0.5 * 0.5 and range of elevation is 1299 to 1489. When I want to export or use copy raster tool or create fill in Arcgis, the results are elevation between -3.40282e+038 and 3.4282e+038 and the map does not show any elevation and range of color. I tried to convert 32 bit to 16 bit but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this...

1. Open ArcCatalog or use the Catalog pane (in ArcMap 10)
2. Browse to the DEM
3. Right-click the DEM and select Calculate Statistics...
4. Accept the default settings and click OK
5. Now Add the DEM to ArcMap

ArcMap uses the statistics to provide the default color ramp based on the Min and Max values. If you still have issues, Right click the DEM in Catalog and look at Properties and see what the Statistics say.